# Use AngularJS ng-repeat element property as div id

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have this HTML:

```
<div data-ng-repeat="curService in sCtrl.myServices" class="ng-cloak" data-ng-if="sCtrl.service==curService.name">
       <br />
       <div id="curService.grid"></div>
</div>
```

and this Angular:

```
ctrl.myServices = [
         {
               name: "Service1",
               grid: "grid1",
               controller: "Controller1 as ctrl1"
         },
         {
               name: "Service2",
               grid: "grid2",
               controller: "Controller2 as ctrl2"
         }
];
```

I would like `curService.grid` to translate to the appropriate string, and have this string as the inner `div`'s id. Is there a way to do this?

**EDIT:** I would also like to set my `ng-controller="{{curService.controller}}"`, but this syntax doesn't seem to work. Any tips?

Answer (score 3):

It's a lot easier than you're probably imagining it to be!

```
<div id="{{ curService.grid }}"></div>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! I'm also trying to set `ng-controller="{{curService.controller}}"` in the repeating div, but that doesn't seem to be working. Is that another easy fix as well?

Comment: Removing the `{{` and `}}` should work, assuming `curService.controller` is a string or a function :)

Comment: After removing the brackets, Angular still doesn't seem to recognize it! When I try to display `{{curService.controller}}`, it just appears as the raw Angular instead of `Controller1 as ctrl1`. If I remove the `ng-controller` property completely, it appears correctly!

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure then. Hopefully someone else will chime in with an answer!